# SQL Find Customers Who Stopped Spending

Tags: sql

I have a problem I am trying to solve based on:

12 months of data for monthly customer subscription payments (Jun17-May17).

There was a price increase in Apr17.

I have identified those customers who paid each month up until Mar17, but how would I now go about finding, of these customers, which ones are no longer paying from Apr17 onwards?

Any pseudo code would be a great help
Thanks

Comment: `Any pseudo code would be a great help` ... I was just going to ask _you_ for that, and sample data would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
select customerId
from t
group by customerId
having max(dte) >= '2017-03-01' and
       max(dte) < '2017-04-01';
```